# Rotating circular menu starting position

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm looking to implement a circular menu which when clicked spins the item selected to a 90 degree angle. However, I need some help in adapting the code to have the end rotation set at 90degrees instead of 0.

I've run through a number of options but can't seem to get to the desired result of a final position of 90 degrees instead of 0.

The code is below and I'm not great with JS so any help would be really appreciated.

```js
const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.result-button'))
const count = buttons.length
const increase = Math.PI * 2 / buttons.length
const radius = 125
let angle = 0

buttons.forEach((button, i) => {
  button.style.top = Math.sin(-Math.PI / 2 + i * increase) * radius + 'px'
  button.style.left = Math.cos(-Math.PI / 2 + i * increase) * radius + 'px'
  button.addEventListener('click', move)
})

function move(e) {
  const n = buttons.indexOf(e.target)
  const endAngle = (n % count) * increase
  console.log(endAngle)
  turn()

  function turn() {
    if (Math.abs(endAngle - angle) > 1 / 8) {
      const sign = endAngle > angle ? 1 : -1
      angle = angle + sign / 8
      setTimeout(turn, 20)
    } else {
      angle = endAngle
    }
    buttons.forEach((button, i) => {
      button.style.top = Math.sin(-Math.PI / 2 + i * increase - angle) * radius + 'px'
      button.style.left = Math.cos(-Math.PI / 2 + i * increase - angle) * radius + 'px'
    })
  }
}
```

```css
.result-options {
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.center {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #3a6d7c;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 4px solid #FFF;
}

.result-button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #96cd5a;
  border: 4px solid #FFF;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="result-options">
  <div class="center">menu
    <div class="result-button">1</div>
    <div class="result-button">2</div>
    <div class="result-button">3</div>
    <div class="result-button">4</div>
    <div class="result-button">5</div>
    <div class="result-button">6</div>
    <div class="result-button">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simplify your code using CSS variables then it will be easy to adjust.

```js
const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.result-button'))
const count = buttons.length

buttons.forEach((button, i) => {
  button.style.setProperty("--r", "calc("+i+"*360deg/"+count+" - var(--d))");
  button.addEventListener('click', move)
})

function move(e) {
  const n = buttons.indexOf(e.target);
  const endAngle = n*360/count;
  document.querySelector('.result-options').style.setProperty("--d", endAngle+"deg");
}
```

```css
.result-options {
  --d:90deg; /* this will control the initial positions */
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin:150px auto 0;
}
.center {
  background-color: #3a6d7c;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display:grid;
  outline: 4px solid #FFF;
}
.center span {
  grid-area:1/1;
}
.result-button {
  grid-area:1/1;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #96cd5a;
  outline: 4px solid #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition:2s;
  transform:rotate(var(--r)) translateX(125px) rotate(calc(-1*var(--r)))
}
```

```html
<div class="result-options">
  <div class="center"><span>menu</span>
    <div class="result-button">1</div>
    <div class="result-button">2</div>
    <div class="result-button">3</div>
    <div class="result-button">4</div>
    <div class="result-button">5</div>
    <div class="result-button">6</div>
    <div class="result-button">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great Temani reply, just curious, what if one wants #1 to be on the 240deg (left center) and when a number is clicked, it rotates to the #1 initial position?